# First program using Pascal

Tags: pascal

im new using Pascal and i have to program a game called seven eleven, can you guys give me some tips?

Ive tried:

```
program sevele;
var capitalinicial: integer
 begin
  writeln('ingrese un capital')
  readln(capitalinicial)
  writeln('su capital es capitalinicial')
```

Comment: You miss several semicolons and some `end` and you need to *compile* your source code.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, There are a few things you need to know:

You have to put a semicolon `;` at the end of every sentence, except after a keyword that denotes the beginning of a control structure (for,while,if,else,etc) or after a `begin` or `end` keyword.

Use the same amount of `begin`s and `end`s keywords. Note that the last `end` in the program is followed by a dot.

When you use `writeln` you can print one or more variables or strings. You have to use simple quotes `'` to print strings, and just the name of a variable without any quote to print it's value, also you need to separe the diferent arguments with commas ','.

for example:

```
program example;
var
  a,b:integer;
  begin
    a:=3;
    b:=5;
    writeln ('this is just a string');
    writeln (a);
    writeln (a,b);
    writeln ('the value of a is: ',a,' and the value of b is: ',b);
    readln;
  end.
```

The code you attemped to write probably is:

```
program sevele;
var capitalinicial: integer;
 begin
  writeln('ingrese un capital');
  readln(capitalinicial);
  writeln('su capital es ',capitalinicial);
  readln; //use this to give you time to view the output
 end.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works

```
program sevele;
var capitalinicial: integer;
begin
writeln('ingrese un capital');
readln(capitalinicial);
writeln('su capital es',capitalinicial);
end.
```